# Optimizing DOM manipulation on scroll? (reducing jittering)

Tags: javascript, performance, electron, editor

**Summary of behavior**: I am writing a text-editor in electron and have been inspecting the rendering behavior of VSC bit by bit from the dev tools to inspire my approach I have currently.

I render a **constant** amount of absolutely positioned  elements (lines) with a fixed height and width that fills 100% of the parent container that will be visible at the location you've scrolled to. Using those fixed number of elements, when scrolling and x number of elements are scrolled away from and not visible anymore, the new absolute position from the top is calculated and set so they remain visible and textContent is updated.

I'm wrapping the callback in a `requestAnimationFrame()` on the "scroll" event listener to throttle the speed at which all this is fired which does help significantly.

I've also computed all the positions for the most part on the JS layer myself and keep references to the DOM elements (divs) alive so I'm only using `.offsetTop` and `.style` properties of the elements on scroll (trying to keep it absolutely cheap as possible). This was *almosttttt* good enough but very randomly I will get some weird jittering where there will be a visible delay from when the lines are displayed onto the screen after adjusting the height.

It's hard to see the issue from the profiler itself because everything looks good as far as I'm aware. Each scroll event takes < 2ms to complete (for VSC this is around ~5ms) and GC is not being invoked at all. CLS doesn't seem like a total issue either because VSC and my implementation looks basically 1:1 in that regard. This behavior still persists nonetheless.

[image: mine2]

[image: mine]

After inspecting the call stack on VSC further and looking at some of the code it looks like they have totally hacked the scroll and built their own version on top of it (this is only an assumption not 100% sure). When the "wheel" event is fired from the mouse they manually set the new scroll position

[image: vscode]

This is something I want to try but I wanted to post this first to see if anyone had any thoughts on this and might know why potentially this could help with the issue?

I tried to make this post as detailed as possible but if anyone has taken the time to read I would love to provide any more context if needed or even link my repo if you would want to take a look at it directly. Thank you!